# Trigger a click event automatically on a dynamic element (DIV) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this HTML page where everything within the `body` is generated dynamically. To use a jQuery slider a DIV `<div id="slider"></div>` is generated. Since the dynamic elements are added to the DOM after the page load I have used a jQuery `on()` to still add the DIV as in the code below using `body` as a static element or container.

```
$("body").on("click", "#slider", function(e){
    $(this).slider({                    
        min:50,
        max:150,
        step: 1,
        value: 100
     });
}
```

My problem now is: the slider only shows up after I click on it, that makes sense since it is bound using the `click event`. How can I trigger that click event automatically to make the slider visible. Mind you the page uses both Ajax and dynamic DIV creation and I have no power to change that.

Comment: Why do you need the click event at all, if you don't want it to require a click? It sounds like you used `.on('click'` because you wanted to automatically run this code when the element became available, but that of course won't work because it still needs a click. Therefore, the same solution that will make the click automatically trigger will also fix the problem without needing the click event handler.

Comment: The HTML+Ajax is generated using Java. All that I have access to is the DIV and when I check the html source I see it is there. But it seems the DIV is added to the DOM much later than after page is loaded. I have tried other ways but to no avail and that was the only way to get the slider working.

Comment: Then unfortunately there's no way of solving this without knowing what HTML+Ajax is generated. You ***need*** to hook into the success callback of the ajax request. The only way of solving this without hooking into the success callback is horribly inefficient and should not be considered as an option ( setInterval loop )

Comment: Can you explain how that could be done. I mean hooking slider in the success callback.

Comment: First we would need to know how the ajax request is being sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having tried everything to no avail I resorted to a workaround using jQuery function call delay i.e. triggering the execution of the click event after a given time (e.g. half a second) from the moment the page is loaded.

```
 $(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("#slider").click()}, 500);
 });
```

This is the only way that worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use trigger however this wouldn't be the best approach to the overall cause just a fix to this specific problem

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**:

```
$("body").on("click", "#slider", function(e){
    $(this).slider({                    
        min:50,
        max:150,
        step: 1,
        value: 100
    });
});

$('body').find('#slider').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I tried that but still it requires me to click on the slider's div to activate and make it visible.

Comment: Try to use `$('body').find('#slider').trigger('click')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the code which Felix as suggested in your Ajax success method once dynamic creation of Div is finished.

```
$('body').find('#slider').trigger('click');
```

I am assuming you are creating div in your ajax success method

Comment: This won't work either. I tried it already. The HTML+Ajax is generated in Java. So I have not access to that code but merely the knowledge that there is a `<div id="slider"></div>` in the page. And looking at the HTML source shows that too.